# How to correctly fix a "dirty" NTFS partition without using chkdsk

Tags: ntfs, disk-check

When I try to do a `ntfsck` to a NTFS partition I get this:

```
sudo ntfsck /dev/sdb1
Unsupported: replay_log()
Volume is dirty.
Unsupported: check_volume()
Checking 161792 MFT records.
Unsupported cases found.
```

How can I clean a "dirty" NTFS volume without having to actually use windows chkdsk tool in the NTFS volume.

I also did a `ntfsfix` and it said that everything was OK but it actually was not.

I also get the same "Dirty" error when trying to check the filesystem using the **Disk Utility**:

[image]

I am starting to think I need some powerful soap.

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but I came across this bootable utility disk that has DOS and a miniXP that looks interesting:  [hirem's boot CD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd)

Comment: Even though you specifically said "Without using Windows", you might have to resort to creating a Windows VM and running `chkdsk` if the below answer doesn't solve your problems. That's what I have to do anyway ;)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try using `ntfsfix`, which was part of the old [ntfsprogs](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ntfsprogs) package and is now located in the [ntfs-3g](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ntfs-3g) package (which you may already have installed).
This is a command line utility which attempts to fix common NTFS problems. It's been a while since I last used it, but it should do its job simply by typing:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
```

It also offers a specific option to clear the "dirty" flag on the partition:

```
sudo ntfsfix -d /dev/sdb1
```

which might or might not be required in addition to the first command. Have a look at `man ntfsfix` for more information.

Comment: I am very sorry. I also did test with that command before doing the ntfsck. I will add it to the question sorry. Also after doing a fix it did not mention anything wrong it just said that everything was ok.

Comment: Even the '-d' option? Well, in that case I don't have much else to contribute, sorry about that..

Comment: Actually ntfsck is the one with the -d parameter but anyway it does not solve the problem. It keeps on telling me that it is a dirty partition. Sounds sexy but is not.

Comment: Yes, it works.  Ubuntu must so it as default operation for such situations

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: @Luis ntfsfix does have a -d option. ntfsck might have one as well (can't find any documentation for this prog) but so does  ntfsfix.

Comment: `ntfsck` is deprecated and no longer distributed. The `-d` option has been integrated into `ntfsfix` instead.

Comment: +1 - This is useful for things like openwrt as well. Thanks!

Comment: For Ubuntu 14.04 use `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g` see http://askubuntu.com/a/513115/112263

Comment: Wow, I had an issue with veracrypt not mounting a disk from an old computer as writeable. Then almost panicked when I in `dmesg` saw `ntfs: (device dm-7): load_system_files(): Volume is dirty.  Mounting read-only.  Run chkdsk and mount in Windows.`. But I tried a single call of `sudo ntfsfix /dev/mapper/veracrypt1`, remounted the drive and BAM! Writing access was back!

Comment: [Before you'll need](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705120/fix-ntfs-partition-is-in-an-unsafe-state-without-windows-installed-and-ntfsfix?rq=1) to `umount /dev/sdb1` or you'll get a _Refusing to operate on read-write mounted device /dev/sdb1_ error.

Comment: I used the ntfsfix tool to clean my NTFS partition, but in addition I had to restart my computer. Just saying if that might help to someone else. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think it may actually be that you need to stop checking it.  :)

I believe I once had similar reports, and I even booted into the original Windows install that made it to run chkdsk, which didn't help.  But what I learned was that Linux couldn't check an NTFS partition, and it should be mounted with the fsckorder set to zero.

I'm not certain if this has changed since then, but hopefully you can crosscheck this to see if it might solve your problem.

Edit:  Forgot to add, I've had no problems with this partition since that time.

Comment: I had the same "Not Clean" dialog on an external NTFS drive when connected to my Ubuntu machine. I ran chkdsk on that drive on a windows machine, and it found no problems with it. I guess that the dialog on Linux is unreliable.

Comment: The check flag does not always mean there are errors on the drive. it only means a check was scheduled for next boot. you can do that (scheduling) manually with ntfsfix or chkdsk. Linux only tells you if the flag is set. and that it does reliably.