# Widows 8 BCD missing with ubuntu dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8

I had just installed Ubuntu in legacy mode with windows 8. I installed Ubuntu to a SSD and the windows os is on my HDD. I was able to use both Ubuntu and windows all day until I force shutdown my laptop when a game caused it to lag. Now when booting windows the BCD is missing information with an error code: `0xc0000034`.

I use grub and the ubuntu os is working perfectly.

I cannot even mount the windows drive in Ubuntu and I get this error:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb5 at /media/mukhil/Windows8_OS: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb5" "/media/mukhil/Windows8_OS"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb5': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Comment: You can fix the partition http://askubuntu.com/a/112161/269282. But to make Windows work again you'll probably need a reinstall/repair.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by running  `powercfg /h off` in windows command terminal. This command usually disable windows hibernate permanently. I follow [this instruction](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/12/disable-hibernation-windows-8/) and now I have full access of windows partition.