# Fix "NTFS Partition is in an Unsafe State" without Windows installed and ntfsfix refusing to operate

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ntfs

Ok, so I just installed my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Gnome 3 and tried to access my old Harddrive (obv NTFS). I can't do it though to the (well-known):

"The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option."

Error, I don't have Windows installed anymore and when I tried to fix it with ntfsfix it just told me that "ntfsfix refuses to operate with read-write mounted device".

This may be a very simple Question, but as I said i'm new to Ubuntu so please don't be too harsh :)

I wan't to access my Drive normally. Thanks  already for everyone helping :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Comment: You'll need Windows to resolve the issue, likely, either a boot repair disk of Windows or otherwise.

Comment: If you do not use Windows, don't use ntfs. The linux tools can not always repair problems with the file system. If you read the error it tells you " mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option" so mount it ro , back up your data, and reformat to ext4

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I **used** Windows and switched to Linux, I didn't know that it can't mout NTFS ...

Comment: Ubuntu can mount ntfs, it just can not always repair the file system as you can see. Mount it ro

Comment: @ThomasW. But why are people then talking aubout ntfsfix ? Just asking because it seems like this is somehow a possibility

Comment: ntfsfix is the tool to try, but it often fails. In that event your options are to boot and repair from windows or mount the partition ro , back up the data, and reformat.

Comment: @njoye 'ntfsfix' isn't the same quality as the tools/kits in Windows.  `ntfsfix` is 'okay', but it is NOTHING compared to the Windows `chkdsk` for checking NTFS integrity.

Comment: Notice that this is NOT a duplicate. The OP has already deleted its windows installation (oops).

Comment: Just because the OP deleted windows does not mean this is not a duplicate as really there is no other solution.

Answer (score 9):

In the past, when you were running Microsoft Windows, much of the disk's data, file metadata, disk metadata and possibly Secret Microsoft Stuff was kept in RAM, for quick, easy access. The way you last shutdown/turned off/pulled the plug on Windows kept it from bringing the disk to a consistent, up-to-date state. Thus, the `The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state....` message.

I'm unfamiliar with `ntfsfix`, but `ntfsfix refuses to operate with read-write mounted device` means that you have the drive mounted with the read-write options, so that any other process can write to the disk while `ntfsfix` is performing disk surgery. This can lead to total confusion and data loss. You *must* unmount the disk first

```
sudo umount /dev/whatever
```

so that when you subsequently run `ntfsfix`, `ntfsfix` can ensure it has exclusive access to the disk. You still may not recover your data, but this will get you closer.

Comment: There is no need for `sudo` here if the same user was the one who mount the partition.