# Cannot access the Windows D: drive from Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted

I completely removed Windows and installed Linux today and now I can't access D:\ . I get that it has something to do with windows partitioning but I can't figure out what to do without removing the sensitive data I got on there. I can't see my D:\ drive in file explorer but I can see it in Gparted. Gparted says that sdb1 is "damaged or unknown to GParted, etc" and sdb2 is working as usual as NTFS.

[image: screenshot]

How do I access my data without removing it on Linux?

Comment: If you've completely removed Windows, then you've probably lost the contents of the D: drive.

Comment: If `sudo mount -a` gives no error, find where `/dev/sdb2` is mounted - you can use [disks][http://i.stack.imgur.com/1DMJB.png] for this purpose - go into this location and check for your files. Maybe only file explorer (nautilus) has a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the File Browser and you should see the drive listed in the left menu:

[image]

Once you click it the drive will mount. It works for NTFS drives out of the box you don't need to install anything.

The only reason I can think it wouldn't work is if your NTFS drive has been marked as "needs to be checked" by Windows, which is a bit more complex of an issue. You can fix that by booting into windows or running the `ntfsfix` command ([see this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112150/how-to-correctly-fix-a-dirty-ntfs-partition-without-using-chkdsk)).

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/9rcT4
Nothing happens when pressed. Also ntfsfix could corrupt my files on the partitions(sdb1 and sbd2 on D:\\)?

Comment: Any commands (including gparted) could cause you to lose data because they are making changes to your disk. You probably want to find out what is causing the disk to not mount before running anything.

If you still have windows boot into it so that your D:\ is marked as clean then boot back into Linux and it should mount the drive with no problem.

If that didn't work or you don't have windows anymore find out why it's not mounting.

Comment: You might be able to see what the error is by manually running the mount command in a terminal `sudo mount -a`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/FJsE0 ? also did sudo mount -a but that just caused the drive to be unavailable in file explorer. Should I create a new partition on the SSD instead and install and boot into windows 8 again and check?

Comment: You should boot into Windows to avoid losing any of those files. I'm pretty confident that `ntfsfix` won't break the drive, but I don't want to see you lose photos of your family or similar.

Comment: @dalom any luck?