Getting an error when I try to access an NTFS drive in my Ubuntu Studio laptop
I need to access an NTFS drive in my Ubuntu Studio laptop. I was using it just fine today. I'm getting the following error message.

An error occurred while accessing 'Basic data partition', the system responded:
The requested operation has failed:
Error mounting /dev/nvme0n1p3 at /media/sallie/3424F0F424F0B9C6: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p3, missing codepage or helper program, or other error


I'd perform file-system checks, as the drive may not have been cleanly ejected during last usage, or used on a windows machine with fastboot etc and thus the file-system isn't left in a clean state (the expectation of fastboot is the same machine only will use it, and the missing data exists in the fastboot/hibernate file that other machines won't have). Providing specific details (what Ubuntu product/release, if any updates had been performed in last session BEFORE this issue etc) may allow us to better help you.

I had the exact same problem with my Ubuntu OS with a NTFS internal drive. I used ............ ntfsfix. https://askubuntu.com/questions/112150/how-to-correctly-fix-a-dirty-ntfs-partition-without-using-chkdsk

I had the same problem with a 500GB Samsung NTFS drive in my Ubuntu 24.04.1 PC, which is not dual-boot. The errors appeared after I had used KDE Partition Manager to examine the drive, even though I did not perform any operations on it.
I was unable to resurrect the drive with any of the Ubuntu utilities. Instead, I had to remove the drive, place it in an external USB enclosure and connect it to a Windows 10 PC, which then automatically repaired it (presumably by running "chkdsk /F /R").
